# Windows 10 x64 fails to install signed device drivers, although everything is reported to be okay

Tags: windows-10, drivers, certificate, device-manager, code-signing

I am currently struggling with Windows 10 device driver signing, my company has developped some drivers for Windows 10 x86 and x64, which I try to sign using a SHA1 certificate. I know SHA1 is not the best option, but should still work as far as I understand the technical documentation from Microsoft.

The actual problem is, that the drivers install correctly, and even if I check them using signtool's verify option, they seem to be okay. Windows 10 also says they are installing fine when installing the INF-file. I have signed all signable files in the driver package, including CAT-files, DLLs, SYS-files, etc.

The point where the drivers actually fail to work is in Windows 10 device manager, there, I get an exclamation mark icon, together with the following description:

"Code 52 - Windows cannot verify the digital signature..."

The workflow I use is exactly as following, of course with other actual data, but the rest is the same.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\stampinf.exe" -f "P:\MyDriver\mydriver.inf" -d 08/11/2017 -v 1.0.0.1

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\Inf2Cat.exe" /driver:"P:\MyDriver" /os:10_X86,10_X64,7_X86,7_X64,8_X86,8_X64,XP_X86,XP_X64

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f 
"C:\Users\me\Documents\MyCert\MyCert.pfx" /p myVerySecretPassw0rd /d "My Drivers" /du "http://www.myveryverycompaniesurl.com" /t "http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll" /v /ph "P:\MyDrivers\*.*"
```

This is what "signtool verify" reports about the driver-files created that way:

```
Verifying: P:\MyDrivers\OneOfMyDLLs.dll

Signature Index: 0 (Primary Signature)
Hash of file (sha1): *************************************************

Signing Certificate Chain:
Issued to: COMODO RSA Certification Authority

Issued by: COMODO RSA Certification Authority

Expires:   Tue Jan 19 01:59:59 2038

SHA1 hash: *************************************************


    Issued to: COMODO RSA Code Signing CA

    Issued by: COMODO RSA Certification Authority

    Expires:   Tue May 09 01:59:59 2028

    SHA1 hash: *************************************************


        Issued to: My Company

        Issued by: COMODO RSA Code Signing CA

        Expires:   Tue Sep 18 01:59:59 2018

        SHA1 hash: *************************************************
```

So for me, everything looks okay, until the point when it comes to device manager, which has some issues with one of the signatures, or generally with how the files are signed, but it doesn't actually give me a hint what is going wrong. Edit: **if Microsoft thinks SHA-1 is insufficient, why is there no error message stating that fact?**

Comment: The problem is the SHA1 certificate. Windows no longer trusts SHA1 certificates for digital signatures like signed drivers and signed applications.  This is a well documented fact

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you link to a source for that (as you say) documented fact? I would like to read about it. Another remaining question is why Windows installs the drivers, but then fails in device manager, during installation and verification, it says that everything is okay which is confusing

Comment: I couldn't tell you when I read the announcement that Windows would stop trusting SHA1 certificates, just that it the announcement said it was going to happen, and based on what you describe it appears to have already happen.  I will go ahead and scavenger up what I can find.

Answer (score 1):

> I know SHA1 is not the best option, but should still work as far as I
>   understand the technical documentation from Microsoft.

The problem is that the current build of Windows 10 does not trust SHA1 code signing certificates.  If you want you can override this behavior by adding the entire certificate chain for your certificate.

[Based on Important change announcement - deprecation of SHA-1](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/973/0/important-change-announcement---deprecation-of-sha-1) directly from Comodo, Windows stop trusting SHA1 code signing certificates back in January 2016.

> January 1 2016 - Microsoft products, including Internet Explorer and
>   Chrome, will cease to trust SHA-1 code signing certificates

Microsoft as of May 2017 stated:

> Today, we intend to do more to warn consumers about the risk of
>   downloading software that is signed using a SHA-1 certificate. Our
>   goal is to develop a common, OS-level experience that all applications
>   can use to warn users about weak cryptography like SHA-1. Long-term,
>   Microsoft intends to distrust SHA-1 throughout Windows in all
>   contexts. Microsoft is closely monitoring the latest research on the
>   feasibility of SHA-1 attacks and will use this to determine complete
>   deprecation timelines.

[Windows Enforcement of SHA1 Certificates](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32288.windows-enforcement-of-sha1-certificates.aspx)

One of the [answers](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/109629/deprecation-of-sha1-code-signing-certificates-on-windows/111978#111978) to [Deprecation of SHA1 code signing certificates on Windows](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/109629/deprecation-of-sha1-code-signing-certificates-on-windows) provided the following table.  The [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/109629/deprecation-of-sha1-code-signing-certificates-on-windows/111978#111978) in question has some safe mitigations to the use of SHA1 certificates.

> [image]

Comment: While there are answers to that question that indicate Microsoft's SHA1 plans changed, the information about the Jan 1 2016 date, didn't actually change.  If you have a certificate that expires in Sept 2018 it means it was signed after Jan 1 2016.  In the end Comodo themselves don't even support SHA1 certificates anymore.

Comment: I have now changed to a SHA-256 certificate, and also create a SHA 256 fingerprint and timestamp. However, that Error Code 52 in device manager with the newly signed drivers is still the same, so I guess it is not a SHA-1 issue anymore. DO you still have any ideas?

Comment: Another thing that comes to my mind: is it possible that my certificate which is actually a code signing certificate, is not sufficient? What's the difference between code signing and driver signing, are that different types of certificates?

Comment: @Erik Yes, they are different but only in the validation process when you are purchasing it